# Number of parallel lines in a given set of lines

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

I am given N lines, i.e, I am given a,b,c for N lines. And each line is of the form ax + by + c = 0. I need to find out the maximum number of lines that are parallel to each other.

For this, first I create a 2 dimensional array of the ratio A/B (-slope) and C/B (-intercept), except for b == 0 (for which I take slope as 1/eps , I have defined eps as a very small positive number).

Then I remove the duplicate entries in $O(n^2)$ complexity.

Again I do $O(N^2)$ scans to find how many lines for a given slope exist and report the maximum number.

It turns out that this a slower way of doing this. How can I make this faster ?

Also, I am writing my code in C++.

Comment: Instead of O(n^2) for both parts, sort it with an O(nlogn) algorithm first and use linear search after it.

Comment: And, because of floating point quirks, for exact results don't use float/double. A special case for vertical lines, and a ratio (ie. a/b as two numbers) for the rest ... lcm etc.etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want in linear time, $O(n)$, by simply using hashing.  You will do two hashes for each line.  The first one to deal with the slope.  So, you will build a hash that segregates lines into buckets of different slopes.  The second hash will segregate lines that have the same slope to ones with different intercepts.

As suggested by deviantfan special case b==0.  Let's deal with that case first.  If b==0, all the lines have the same slope, throw them all into the same slope bucket.  If b!=0, the calculate your slope A/B and hash that to get a unique slope bucket.  Note, you might get some collisions in  slope buckets and you can use any of the standard methods for dealing with that (e.g. a secondary hash of slope using a different function or simply building a binary tree of slopes in a bucket if you don't mind collisions being $O(n*log(n))$).

Okay, at this point your line should be in a unique slope bucket, now hash the intercept C/A (for b=0 and a!=0) or C/B (for b!=0), and a special bucket for (a=0 and b=0, for which c=0 is a requirement--do the algebra to prove this to yourself).  That will allow you to figure out distinct lines within a given slope bucket--each distinct line will be in a distinct hash bucket on intercept.  Of course, again, you may have to deal with collisions from your hash and the same techniques would apply.

If you keep track of how many unique intercept buckets you have in each unique slope bucket, you can then do a linear search over the slope buckets to find the largest number.  You could also simply keep a pair with (max value (of intercept buckets), slope) as you build the structure and skip the final search.  That doesn't change the asymptotic complexity, since all the operations are linear.

The only final thing to be careful of is the vagaries of floating point arithmetic.  It isn't clear to me whether you want true comparisons on inequality of your slope and intercept calculations or whether you might want to do some form of rounding to deal with 1.99999... =? 2.0.  There also might be issues when either A or B is either very large or very small.  A lot of this depends upon your application.